# Displaying equations in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

What's the best way to display equations in a UILabel?  The equations will be generated by MS Equation editor.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I don't know how I could do it, but I misread `UILabel` for `UIButton`... here the corrected answer...

I suppose that MS Equation editor can produce a PNG, JPEG, GIF, or bmp (windows format) image for the equation.

In this case, you can add your image to a `UILabel` as a subview.

```
 NSString* pathToEquation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"eq" ofType:@"png"];
 UIImage* equationImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathToEquation];
 UIImageView* equationView = [UIImageView initWithImage:equationImage];
 equationView.frame = CGRectMake(....); // -- where the image should appear within the label
 [label addSubview:equationView];
```

This should work.
Don't forget to include all image files as resources into your project.

Comment: Or you could just use UIImageView?

Comment: The problem is I'm building a framework that will produce multiple apps.  I really need to be able to pull these, in text, from a csv file and plug them in to a label.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing - to show complex math equations in iOS devices. Please see this post where I have provided my solution  -> 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845496/display-complex-mathematical-equations-in-ios-5-0-devices